# Disable access to Windows Start menu via Winkey

Tags: windows-7

I would like to remove Winkey's ability to open Start menu, however I don't want to get rid of this key altogether as I want all the current functionality of this key (like Win+tab) to be preserved.

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

From [AutoHotkey Example Scripts](http://xahlee.info/mswin/autohotkey_examples.html) :

```
;; disable Win key behavior of popping up the Start Menu
;; but Win+‹key› should still work
~LWin Up::Return
~RWin Up::Return
```